# How to use both data validation "list" and at add any value in a cell?

Tags: excel

For example, I have a list of names of fruits, but sometimes I need to add other names of fruits that are not listed. How can I do that without break down the data validation "list"?

Comment: Provide more details please. What do you intend to do when you need to add other names of fruits? At least, you need to add them *somewhere*. A picture of how it is now, how you would like it to be is also helpful in describing what you are trying to achieve (you cannot attach pictures, but you can give links to pictures).

Comment: consider about accepting answer on previous questions, before posing new. See this link for details: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: @Jerry I have column A with the list of fruits. I need to add a name of fruits that is not in the list and the name must be in the same column A. How can I do so without change the data validation list?

Comment: And what do you have so far when you tried to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the list as an assist, but to still be able to enter any data you want, just turn off the error alert in the data validation settings. If you need to validate the data entered, you will need to add it to the list, as Jerry suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the names of fruits you want to add to data validation list in a vertical list of cells. Go to data validation on data menu and under list select the entire range of cells containing the names of fruits as also some blank cells below the list. Close the Data Validation window. Now the list of fruits appear in the drop down list. The names of additional fruits can be added in the blank cells in the range. The new names automatically appear in the drop down list.